# Start next line from the first for text view

Tags: android

[image]

I have two text view in each line and I want the next line to start from the start of layout but it starts from where the text view is placed. Is there any attribute for the text view to achieve this ?

```
  <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/relative_english"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="MainTranslation:"
                android:textColor="@android:color/holo_green_light"
                android:id="@+id/english_lable_offer"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
                android:text="saf"
                android:id="@+id/tv_english_show_offer"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/english_lable_offer"
                android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/english_lable_offer" />


        </RelativeLayout>
```

This is my text views code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is impossible. But if you want to achive this feauture, you must put only one TextView in a line and merge the strings you have.

Comment: but theier fonts are diffrent and i dont want to use Spannable  .

Comment: Why don't you want to use Spannable?

Answer (score 0):

That is all what you have to do ....
Change Relative to linear and set android:orientation = "vertical"

```
<LinearLayout
android:padding="5dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
android:id="@+id/relative_english"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
```

Comment: but this way the second text view comes under first text view . what i need to be done is the rest of text stand under first text view